# VSCodeで右クリックからファイルを開くとそれまで開いていたファイルが閉じてしまう

Tags: vscode

VSCodeではA、B、Cというファイルをダブルクリックして開く場合、タブの要領でA、B
、Cと横に開いていきますよね？
そして、一旦VSCodeを閉じて、今度はDというファイルをダブルクリックで開くと、VSCodeが起動して、A、B、C、Dと横に開いた状態になります。
しかし、Dを右クリックからOpen with Codeで開くと、同じようにVSCodeが起動しますが、A、B、Cが消えてDだけが開いた状態になってしまいます。
右クリックから開いてもA、B、C、Dと表示させるためには、どのように設定すれば良いのでしょうか？

---

OSはWindows 10です。

Comment: [本家SOの類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50889658)に回答はなく、「[Githubのissue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34529)で議論されてるけど開発ロードマップにはまだ載ってないね」というコメントがありました。実際に`"window.restoreWindows": "all"` `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"` `"files.hotExit": "onExit"`などの設定をしても要望通りの動作はしないため、現在の機能では実現できないように思います。ちなみに`File`→`Open Recent`→`Reopen Closed Editor`メニューを選択しても前回起動時のファイルを開きなおすことはできませんでした。

Comment: わざわざ調べていただき、ありがとうございます。個人的にはすごく不便なんですが、世の中的にはそうでもないんでしょうか・・・