# コンテキストメニューからVSCodeでファイルを開くと既存のワークスペースが閉じられてしまう

Tags: vscode

WindowsでコンテキストメニューからVSCodeでファイルを開くようにしたのですが、VSCodeが起動していない状態でファイルを開くと既存のワークスペースが閉じられてしまいます。VSCodeを起動した状態では開いたファイルが追加されます。
起動していない状態でも既存のワークスペースにファイルを追加する方法はないでしょうか?
コンテキストメニューの起動コマンドは"G:\Tools\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "%1"です。
起動オプション-aゃ-rを試してみましたがいずれもダメでした。
ヘルプを表示させたら起動オプションが表示されるかと思い、code -hも試しましたがcodeが起動するだけでヘルプは表示されませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 開きたいファイルがワークスペースに登録されているフォルダ外のファイルだった場合、どうしたいですか？　`code --add` でワークスペースにフォルダを追加することはできますが、ファイルの場合はどこまで上位のフォルダまで見るかという問題が発生します。 https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Comment: 希望としては追加で開きたいですのですが、やはりファイルの場合は無理なんでしょうかね。

Comment: 無理かどうかを判断する前に、「追加で開く」とはどういう動作をしてほしいのかより詳しく知りたいな、というコメントでした。ワークスペースに対してできる操作は「ルートとなるフォルダを追加する」であって「ファイルを追加する」ではないためです。

Comment: 「より詳しく」という意味がよくわかりません。私としては質問にある通り「既存のワークスペースにファイルを追加したい」だけです。

Comment: まず、ワークスペースに追加されるのはフォルダであってファイルではないことをご理解ください: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces 。それとは別に、VS Code でフォルダーを開いているときにメニューから「ファイルを開く」をするとエディター上でワークスペース外のファイルを開けますが、これはワークスペースに追加している訳ではありません。このため本当にワークスペースに追加したいのであれば、どのフォルダーをルートとして登録しますか、という部分を選べます（すぐ上のフォルダを選ぶ、git root を選ぶ、など）。これが「より詳しく」の部分でした。あるいはワークスペースに追加するのではなく単にファイルを開きたいのだ、というお話もあるでしょう。私はこちらの方向で調べていたのですが、`window.openFilesInNewWindow` など関連する設定はいくつかあるものの所望の動作をするものが無いなあとなっていたところでした。

Comment: コマンドラインオプションの解説はこちら。[Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

Comment: コマンドラインオプションはいちおう調べてみたのでファイルの追加は無理なのかなという感じはしてました。なので何か別の方法がないものかと思い質問に至った訳です。不思議に思うのは、ワークスペースに登録したフォルダ直下の編集中のファイルであってもcodeを起動していない状態でコンテキストから開くと既存のワークスペースが閉じられてしまうことです。そうするとコンテキストで開いたファイルを閉じてからワークスペースを開いて再度同じファイルを開くことになるのでとても不便に思います。なのでこのような質問になりました。

Comment: 参考: 過去の類似質問(重複候補) - [VSCodeで右クリックからファイルを開くとそれまで開いていたファイルが閉じてしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48410) / 過去には GitHub の issue で機能要望が議論されていたみたいですが実現には至っていない？様子。

Comment: やはり不便だと思う方はほかにもいらしたんですね。ほぼ2年前からこの状態が続いているということは解決は難しかな。コンテキストに登録して便利になるかと思いきや、このような状態ではかえって不便なので当面はCodeは終了させず常駐させて使用します。